# ClassNotFoundException in SparkStreaming Example

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am new to Spark streaming and trying to run a example from [this](https://www.supergloo.com/fieldnotes/how-to-apache-spark-streaming-with-scala-part-1/) tutorial and I am following **MAKING AND RUNNING OUR OWN NETWORKWORDCOUNT**.
I have completed 8th step and made a jar from sbt.

Now I am trying to run deploy my jar using the command in 9th step like this:

```
bin/spark-submit --class "NetworkWordCount" --master spark://abc:7077 target/scala-2.11/networkcount_2.11-1.0.jar localhost 9999
```

but when I run this command I get following exception:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: NetworkWordCount
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)   at
>   org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:229)    at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:700)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

jar that I have created contains **"NetworkWordCount"** class having the following code from the spark examples

```
package src.main.scala

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}

object NetworkWordCount {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    if (args.length < 2) {
      System.err.println("Usage: NetworkWordCount <hostname> <port>")
      System.exit(1)
    }

    //StreamingExamples.setStreamingLogLevels()

    // Create the context with a 1 second batch size
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("MyNetworkWordCount")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(1))

    val lines = ssc.socketTextStream(args(0), args(1).toInt, StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)
    val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(" "))
    val wordCounts = words.map(x => (x, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
    wordCounts.print()
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

I am unable to identify what am I doing wrong.

Comment: I think the exception says what the issue is: `Warning: Local jar /usr/local/spark/target/scala-2.11/networkcount_2.11-1.0.jar does not exist, `  check that out.

Comment: made target/scala-2.11 directory and placed my jar there, now the warning has vanished but the exception is still there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `spark-submit` parameter `--class` takes a fully qualified class name. 
In the case of the code above, it should be `src.main.scala.NetworkCount`

```
bin/spark-submit --class src.main.scala.NetworkCount --master spark://abc:7077 target/scala-2.11/networkcount_2.11-1.0.jar localhost 9999
```

Note: the package name used looks like an IDE setup issue. `src/main/scala` is the typical root for a `scala` code base, and not a package name.

Comment: @M.AhsenTaqi good to know. I wish you success with your learning path.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have the "target/scala-2.11/networkcount_2.11-1.0.jar" file in your current dir when executing spark-submit

Comment: I have tried it but the warning has vanished but exception is still there

Comment: @M.AhsenTaqi why your package name is src.main.scala? Usually it's set as root source dir but not package name, if you don't have a package, remove the "package src.main.scala" line